# Crear un salto de Linea en Crystal Report desde Java

Tags: java, crystal-reports, report

Estoy haciendo un programa en JAva con el IDE Eclipse.

En Java hago la consulta SQL y me trae los datos en un ArrayList
creo el objeto y lo guardo en el ArrayList

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego esos se lo envio a la clase que le manda los al reporte creado en Crystal Report

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alli le estoy pasando los datos a la variable Preguntas y Respuestas lo que tiene el objeto. Al estar en un FOR es porque en las Preguntas y Respuestas son varoles multiples y quiero que en el informa se muestre algo a si

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en el reporte me sale asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la foto me esta poniendo varias preguntas en la misma linea y si no caben se trunca y sigue poniendo mas preguntas y cada pregunta se ve que la sepera por el caracter , (coma) que es la que indica que es una nueva pregunta.

esta coma se pone automaticamente.

Como se le hace para que quede cada pregunta en una linea nueva.

Mensiiono que este reporte no tiene ninguna base de datos conectada los campos que tengo no tienen niguna formula. solamente hice los campos y los acomode y ya . no le movi nada mas . bueno excepto la opcion que mi campo sea multiple y que cresca automaticamente. eso estodo.

y ya intente desde el codigo enviar saltos de lineas pero ninguna funcioona

\u0010 \u0013 \ln todo estos intente y se sigue mostrando todo igual.

si no encuentro como creo un salto de linea desde java  tendre que hacer como 50 campos en crystal report  (calculo que no son mas de 50 preguntas) y llamarlos cada uno desde el java. ya que ahorita es un solo campo que crece automaticamente conforme la informacion.

vi tambien que se puede hacer con el chr(10) o chr(13) pero estas funciones no estan en Java.

espero darme explicar gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con la etiqueta "< br >", jasperreports reconoce html

Comment: guaaa te la rifastesss

Comment: tambien tuve que moverle al Formato de la Varibale en Crystal Report en la Pestaña Parrafo y en la opcion que dice Interpretacion del Texto lo pase de ninguno a HTML

y con eso funcion al 100. gracias

Comment: ya tenia como 2hr buscando y no ma no. estaba apunto de ver un tutorial de como hacer formulas en Crystal Report haber si por alli iba el asunto de jajaja, tambien busque como hacer Wrap pero tampoco encontre

pero ya quedo listo, eso era todo lo que faltaba para terminar el reporte